# How to fade a div parent and it's respective childrens?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to use jQuery to fade a particular div which contains a few other child divs.  I tought it would work but I think there is more to that...  Can anyone help me out what's the best way to fade all the elements of the parent div?

Currently using the following, but only the background of the parent div is fading and the childs are just hidden or shown without any fade for some reason.

```
$("#PopupView").fadeIn();
$("#PopupView").fadeOut();
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Popup View -->
            <div id="PopupView">
                <div class="numCont">
                    <div class="bgNum"></div>
                    <div class="bgNumAni"></div>
                    <div id="txtPageNumber" class="number">3</div>
                </div>
                <div class="bottomRectangle">PAGE</div>
                <div class="leftArrow"></div>
                <div class="rightArrow"></div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
#PopupView {
    position:absolute;
    top:53px;
    left:0px;
    width:604px;
    height:289px;
    z-index:99;
    background-image:url(../../res/drawable/list_bg.gif);
}

#PopupView .numCont {
    position:absolute;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    left: 256px;
    top: 85px;
}

#PopupView .numCont .number {
    position:absolute;
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align:center;
    color: #2884ff;
    top: 16px;
    left:0px;
}

#PopupView .numCont .bgNum {
    position:absolute;
    width:68px;
    height:68px;
    top: 6px;
    left: 6px;
    background-color:#0b0b0b;
}

#PopupView .numCont .bgNumAni {
    position:absolute;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image:url(../../res/drawable/list_loadingBlocks_v1.gif);
    visibility:hidden;
}

#PopupView .bottomRectangle {
    position:absolute;
    width:68px;
    height:13px;
    left: 262px;
    top: 160px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    color: #414141;
    background-color:#080808;
    padding-top:2px;
}

#PopupView .leftArrow {
    position:absolute;
    width:32px;
    height:31px;
    left: 11px;
    top: 124px;
    background-image:url(../../res/drawable/list_leftArrow_normal.png);
}

#PopupView .rightArrow {
    position:absolute;
    width:32px;
    height:31px;
    left: 562px;
    top: 124px;
    background-image:url(../../res/drawable/list_rightArrow_normal.png);
}
```

Comment: `$("#PopupView").fadeOut();` should automatically fade out the PopupView div and all its children. Is it not working?

Comment: What exactly is the problem, `$('#PopupView').fadeOut(1000);` works for me (at least in jsfiddle).

Comment: Thanks for the fast replies!  I have tried $("#PopupView").fadeIn(); and fades the parent background properly but the childrens are shown right away without fading in.

Comment: `$("#PopupView").fadeOut(1000);` should work. Try calling it on it's children, too `$("#PopupView div").fadeOut(1000)` if they are still showing, hide them after on the fadeout callback, then show them on the fadeIn callback. Does that work? I don't have any experience in the browser you are using, just thought I would give it a shot.

Comment: I can actually fade a child if I specifically say $("#leftArrow").fadeOut(1000); assuming I gave the id="leftArrow" to one of the child divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this is what your looking for?

```
$("#PopupView").hide("slow");
```

to show it again use this:

```
$("#PopupView").show("fast");
```

reference is here: http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Using hide() seems to tween the PopupView to the left top corner of the screen... I'm using a browser called Maple.

Comment: try $("#PopupView").fadeOut("slow");

Comment: `.hide()` will do that. It should *still* hide the children. Does it do that? Does `$("#PopupView").css("display","none")` hide everything?

Comment: @Jason, yes $("#PopupView").css("display","none") does hide everything

Comment: @etoxin I have tried that and only the parent fades out and at the end of the fade the childs are hidden without any fading fx.

Comment: I will an add an answer with what I you could try so it looks better than in a comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#PopupView").fadeOut("slow")
```

or

```
$("#PopupView").fadeOut(500)
```

You can change the value 500 to some other number to adjust the speed of fading

Comment: Only the parent background fades with this method not the childrens. It would be smart to point out that I'm using a browser called Maple and it stinks but I'm also new to JS so I'm not sure what is a bug and what's just me not doing things correctly....

Comment: fadeOut will fades everything in the browser.I checked with IE,Firefox and it works.Hows it working in these browsers ?

Comment: Well the particular Maple browser is used by Samsung TVs and I was trying to build an app for the TV and this particular issue has appeared and since I'm also new to JS I thought maybe I'm doing something wrong....

Answer (score 0):

I should of seen this before. its because the child elements are:

```
position:absolute;
```

change them to:

```
position:inline;
```

and the should fade.

Comment: You got me a little excited for a sec... :P Unfortunately I tried it same result the childs don't fade and at the end of the fade they are just hidden...

Comment: do they fade with basic css no positioning?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in your comments, the children are not staying hidden. Try this (though it is way more work than I would think you would have to do);

```
$("#PopupView").fadeOut(300, function(){ $(this).find("div").css("display","none");});
```

then on fade back in:

```
$("#PopupView").fadeIn(300, function(){ $(this).find("div").css("display","block");});
```

or you can use `.css("visibility","hidden")` and `.css("visibility","visible")`

Let me know what this does? Again, in most browsers

```
$("#PopupView").fadeOut(100);
```

would work just fine. Never messed with Maple.

EDIT:

Or better yet, try fading everything out explicitly:

```
$("#PopupView").fadeOut(100);
$("#PopupView div").fadeOut(100);
```

and their opposites. *Something* should get what you want!

Comment: Thanks for the efforts to help me out! The issue is that the childrens are not fading together with the parent.  At a fadeIn the childrens are just shown not faded in and at the fadeOut the childrens are just hidden at the end of the fade without them having any fading effect.

Answer (score 0):

made this, tested and works.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#PopupView").bind('click', function(){
            alert("boom");
            $("#PopupView").fadeOut('slow');
        });
    })
    </script>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
#PopupView {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    /*top:53px;*/
    /*left:0px;*/
    width:604px;
    height:289px;
    z-index:99;
    background:red;
}
#PopupView .numCont {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    /*left: 256px;*/
    /*top: 85px;*/
}
#PopupView .numCont .number {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align:center;
    color: #2884ff;
    /*top: 16px;*/
    /*left:0px;*/
}
#PopupView .numCont .bgNum {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    width:68px;
    height:68px;
    /*top: 6px;*/
    /*left: 6px;*/
    background-color:#0b0b0b;
}
#PopupView .numCont .bgNumAni {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
    /*top: 0px;*/
    /*left: 0px;*/
    background-image:url(../../res/drawable/list_loadingBlocks_v1.gif);
    visibility:hidden;
}
#PopupView .bottomRectangle {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    width:68px;
    height:13px;
    /*left: 262px;*/
    /*top: 160px;*/
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:3px;
    color: #414141;
    background-color:#080808;
    padding-/*top:2px;*/
}
#PopupView .leftArrow {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    width:32px;
    height:31px;
    /*left: 11px;*/
    /*top: 124px;*/
    background-image:url(../../res/drawable/list_leftArrow_normal.png);
}
#PopupView .rightArrow {
    /*position:absolute;*/
    width:32px;
    height:31px;
    /*left: 562px;*/
    /*top: 124px;*/
    background-image:url(../../res/drawable/list_rightArrow_normal.png);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Popup View -->
<div id="PopupView">
    <div class="numCont">
        <div class="bgNum">
        </div>
        <div class="bgNumAni">
        </div>
        <div id="txtPageNumber" class="number">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomRectangle">
        PAGE
    </div>
    <div class="leftArrow">
    </div>
    <div class="rightArrow">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```